# Как правильно пользоваться Elevation и Translation Z

Tags: java, android, material-design

Помогите разобраться, с этими свойствами. Разницу я понял elevation - это базовая глубина view, а translation z - это динамическая переменная, и используется для анимации.

Вопрос вот в чем, в гайдлайнах гугла описывается каким образом view-хи должны располагаться на плоскости следуя концепции material design.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, каким образом мне компоновать эти свойства?
Если у button я выставлю elevation=2 и translationz=8, я добьюсь правильного эффекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть обоих параметров одинакова, изменение высоты за счет добавления тени, разница только в том, что **elevation** это статический параметр, а **translationZ** динамический, поэтому может использоваться для создания анимации.

В обычном макете, без анимации, от обоих параметров получится одинаковый эффект. А совмещение `elevation="2dp"` и `translationZ="8dp"`, это то же самое что `"10dp"` одного из параметров.

Для достижения эффекта как на второй картинке, просто увеличьте значение, например до `"13dp"`.

Comment: Понял, благодарю!